# Multi horizontal barplots in one plot

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

Does anybody whether its possible to get multiple horizontal bar plots in one plot. Say I have two horizontal bars plots (attached) which both use the same y-axis data. But their x-value data differs. Can I get these two plots in one plot?

I have attached my bar plots and code that i use to plot

Plot the first hbar

```
plt.barh(index,b1_plt,color = 'K')    
plt.barh(index,b2_plt,color = 'K')
plt.xlabel('Width')
plt.ylabel('layer nr')
plt.title('Section outline')
```

Plot the second hbar

```
plt.barh(index,micro_xmi_all) 
plt.xlabel('Micro strain')
plt.ylabel('layer nr')
plt.title('Strain diagram')
```

The list micro_xmi_all have different range than b1_plt or b2_plt

[image]

Comment: I don't think it is clear what you are asking here. Successive calls of `plt.barh` *will* plot the bars in the same diagram. If this is not the case, please provide a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: Do you need a [`twiny`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.twiny.html) axes, perhaps? You could see [this example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html), changing `twinx` to `twiny`.

Comment: Hello guys, thank you very much for your answers ! Im sorry perhaps i could be more clear. Say i have two figures which has identical vertical axis (layer nr) but their horizontal axis are different. One has micro strains in the range (-600 to 1000) while the other deal with the geometry (0,5- 1 m). Can these two figure be put side by side as they are sharing the same vertical axis?